# Why are django form variables made static members instead of instance members

Tags: django, django-forms

I currently have a form object that looks like this

```
class MainLoginForm(forms.Form):
    PART_CHOICES = (
        ("0", "0"),
        ("1", "1"),
    )

    user_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    user_category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PART_CHOICES)
    user_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
```

I then use this object in the following manner in my view

```
def home(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MainLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Hello World')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = MainLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Everything seems to work except that I am curious as to why the object i created has class members and not instance members such as this ? I just started learning Django and was curious ..

```
class MainLoginForm(forms.Form):
        PART_CHOICES = (
            ("0", "0"),
            ("1", "1"),
        )
        def __init__(self)
        self.user_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.user_category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PART_CHOICES)
        self.user_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
```

Wouldnt the current way be unsafe when multiple simultaneous requests come in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following syntax is called **Declarative Syntax**:

```
class MainLoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

You can have a look at the comments in [`forms.Form`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L487)

> ```
> class Form(six.with_metaclass(DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass, BaseForm)):
>       "A collection of Fields, plus their associated data."
>       # This is a separate class from BaseForm in order to abstract the way
>       # self.fields is specified. This class (Form) is the one that does the
>       # fancy metaclass stuff purely for the semantic sugar -- it allows one
>       # to define a form using declarative syntax.
>       # BaseForm itself has no way of designating self.fields.
> ```

You have to notice that the fields you define in the form like above are only available in `self.fields['user_name']` and not directly as `self.user_name` where `self` is referring to the form instance.

The `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` is responsible for reading the fields defined using declarative syntax and then populating `self.fields` on the form instance.

---

> Wouldnt the current way be unsafe when multiple simultaneous requests come in ?

It is not exactly clear what you mean by unsafe because that is very subjective here. But, on the othe rhand if you just meant the fields being defined on the class level, then you can see in the explanation above that it is not the case. So from that perspective the current method is safe.

---

If you do wish to create a form where the fields needs to be defined within `__init__` method, you have to store the fields in a dict and update the `self.-fields` collection:

```
class MainLoginForm(forms.Form):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MainLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         # create a new field 
         self.fields['user_name'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you?